# Getting json on cross domain with jsonp using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I have a very simple $.ajax call that is suppose to get the json data from a given url. Currently the url does get called and the data does get returned, however the localHsonpCallback function doesn't seem to get fired.

Here is my code.

```
function getBuildings(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/api/users',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: "localJsonpCallback"
    });
}

function localJsonpCallback(json) {
console.log("Fired");
    if (!json.Error) {
        console.log("Fired");
    }
    else {
        console.log("ERROR");
    }
}
```

So as mentioned above for some reason the localJsonpCallback doesn't seem to get fired at all.

Also I should mention that in my Chrome Dev tools the request link ends up looking like this for reason

```
http://localhost/api/users?callback=localJsonpCallback&_=1429708885454
```

Any help in this question would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: [This indicates](http://jsfiddle.net/hpqnr6Ln/) that your code is working, although that code is using JSONP (ie it's wrapped in a function)

Answer (score 0):

Try the callback method as an anonymous function directly inside the parameter list.

```
function getBuildings(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/api/users',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonpCallback: function(data){
            console.log("Fired");
            if (!data.Error) {
                console.log("Fired");
            }
            else {
                 console.log("ERROR");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If youre not appending the callback onto the url you can set the jsonp oprion to false and then, as you are doing, set the callback in the options.

```
function getBuildings(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/api/users',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: "localJsonpCallback"
    });
}
```

Since javascript is sequential its also a good idea to define your functions before theyre called. ie - define your callback function before your ajax call.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

jsonp

> Type:
>   String Override the callback function name in a JSONP request.
>   This value will be used instead of `'callback'` in the `'callback=?'` part
>   of the query string in the url. So `{jsonp:'onJSONPLoad'}` would result
>   in `'onJSONPLoad=?'` passed to the server. As of jQuery 1.5, setting the
>   jsonp option to false prevents jQuery from adding the `"?callback"`
>   string to the URL or attempting to use `"=?"` for transformation. In
>   this case, you should also explicitly set the jsonpCallback setting.
>   For example, `{ jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "callbackName" }`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this piece of code it will help solve your problem:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',   
      url: 'http://localhost/api/users',
      data:{todo:"jsonp"},
      dataType: "jsonp",
      crossDomain: true,         
      cache:false,
      success: success,
      error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert(errorThrown);
      }
 });

 var success = function(data){            
        /* parse JSON */
        data = $.parseJSON(data);
        //your code here
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

This either a server side problem that the callback parameter is not used properly or the parameter name `callback` does not exist for the server side they are looking for something different.

You said the result is returning, what is the format? JSONP must return a script block not pure data so be sure the result is in below format.

```
{callbackFunctionName}({hugeDataFromServer});
```

Basically it is script that calls your function.

if it is not the server side that means it is more likely they are using a different name for `callback` parameter e.g. `cb` , `_callback` etc

Comment: the returned data looks something like this. [
 {
  "id":1,
  "name": "Kanye"
 },
 {
  "id":2,
  "name": "Drake"
 }
]

Comment: if this is the output of the jsonp request not a debug result it is wrong. I believe the server side does not configured for jsonp or you are sending wrong parameter. can you add some server side code  for api/users requests.